# What is this symbol that looks like a hook with a 90 degree arrow pointing at it?

Tags: identification, schematics, symbol

I have a schematic and there's this symbol I don't understand. I tried reading list of circuit symbols but couldn't find a match.

[image]

Comment: For future visitors and the search functionality, it would be useful to describe the symbol in the text as well.

Comment: I think it is part of an edge connector for a jack plug. It would help if you included more of the circuit diagram, rather than just a small sniplet.

Comment: @jippie Now that you mention it, it is. There was a space in between them so I thought they're two seperate symbols. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used for the switch part of a connector, commonly for an audio connector where the connecter is used for an external speaker (or microphone) and the switch disables the internal speaker. The full symbol is like this:

[image]

(This picture calls the middle contact 'connect', IMO 'disconnect' would be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a combination of a jack plug and a switch. When you insert the plug from the left, the V contact touches the plug contact instead of making contact with the arrow point. Often used as a method of disconnecting speakers when plugging in headphones.